# How to dynamically have buttons that render different information depending on the buttons id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of messages that I display by mapping through them. Each of these messages has its own + box that when pressed I want to show more information about that specific message. I am having issues with being able to target that messages specific box so that each plus box when pressed only show the info related to it.

Ive tried putting an event on the onClick function and if the event.target.id matches the message id, then it runs a function.

```
class AllMessages extends Component {
    handleBoxOpen () {
        alert('hi')
    }

        Messages = () => {
        return messages.map((item, i) => {
            return (
                <AllMessagesContainer>
                    <MainMessagesContainer>
                        <BoxButtonContainer key={i} dataId={item.id}>
                            <BoxButton onClick={(event) => event.target.id === item.id ? this.handleBoxOpen() : '' }>
                                <i class="far fa-plus-square"></i>
                            </BoxButton>
                        </BoxButtonContainer>
                        <SenderContainer>
                            <Sender>{item.sender}</Sender>
                        </SenderContainer>
                        <BodyContainer>
                            <Body>{item.body}</Body>
                        </BodyContainer>
                        <TypeContainer>
                            <Type>{item.type}</Type>
                        </TypeContainer>
                        <DateContainer>
                            <Date>{item.sentDate}</Date>
                        </DateContainer>
                    </MainMessagesContainer>
                </AllMessagesContainer>
            )  
        })
   }
```

I expect the alert to be displayed when one of the boxes is clicked but nothing is happening because the conditions are obviously not being met.

Comment: You can either have an array of bools in the `state` of the `AllMessages` component and change the appropriate element using the `i` index from the map function, or you create a separate component for a single message box that manages its own open/close state. Regarding your code, why do you have tons of components like that? And why is your code rendering multiple `AllMessagesContainer` instances? The name sounds like there should only be one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass an id prop to the box button, and add it to the clickable component:

```js
<BoxButton
    id={item.id}
    onClick={(event) => { event.target.id === item.id ? this.handleBoxOpen() : ''; }}
>
    <i class="far fa-plus-square"></i>
</BoxButton>
```

But I would prefer to manage your items with a state:

```js
<BoxButton
    id={item.id}
    onClick={() => { this.handleBoxOpen(item.id); }}
>
    {
        this.state[item.id] ? (
            <i class="far fa-plus-square"></i>
        ) : (
            <i class="far fa-minus-square"></i>
        )
    }
</BoxButton>

handleBoxOpen(id) {
    alert(id);
    // Do something with the id for example
    this.setState({ [id]: !this.state[id] });
    // Or
    this.setState({ selected: id });
}
```